# why use condition_variable when we already have a notifying variable?

Tags: c++, multithreading, condition-variable

Consider the following code:

```
int main() { 
    bool done = false; 
    condition_variable con;
    mutex m;

    thread producer([&]() {
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(10)); 
        done = true;
        //con.notify_one();
    });

    thread consumer([&]() {
        /*unique_lock<mutex> lock(m);
        while (!done) {
            con.wait(lock);
        }*/
        while (!done);
        cout << "now my turn..."<<endl;
    });

    producer.join();
    consumer.join(); 
}
```

if I uncomment the code in the 2 threads, I will use the condition_variable. So the consumer thread will look like this:

```
thread consumer([&]() {
    unique_lock<mutex> lock(m);
    while (!done) {
        con.wait(lock);
    } 
    // while (!done); <-this is equivalent of the above
    cout << "now my turn..."<<endl;
});
```

It seems that I can achieve the same thing with/without condition_variable.
So my question is: why do we need condition_variable if a notifying variable ('done' variable in this case) has been used already? What is the benefit of using it? Can I do something that a notifying variable cannot do?

Comment: Look up blocking vs. non-blocking.

Comment: You would at least want a little sleep time in that while loop or your CPU use is going to **SPIKE** for no reason at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When waiting on a condition variable the thread is blocked (i.e. not executing). When notified the thread is put in the ready state so the OS can schedule it.

This is more efficient than the thread "busy-waiting", which is polling a variable constantly to check that it can continue. In that case the thread is using up CPU cycles that could be used for actual work instead.

Also you need to use condition variables in order to correctly protect the critical section from being accessed by multiple threads at a time. You might have 3 consumers running but only one is allowed to work at a time (the others might be doing something else until then).